# Thymeleaf Template Resolver prefix with Gradle

Tags: spring-mvc, amazon-web-services, spring-boot, gradle, thymeleaf

I'm trying to deploy a Spring Boot application built with Gradle in AWS Elastic Beanstalk but I keep getting this error:

```
2017-07-05 13:47:17.913 ERROR 2804 --- [nio-5000-exec-7] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates//articulos/index.html]")] with root cause

java.io.FileNotFoundException: class path resource [templates//articulos/index.html] cannot be opened because it does not exist
    at org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource.getInputStream(ClassPathResource.java:172) ~[spring-core-4.3.7.RELEASE.jar!/:4.3.7.RELEASE]
    at org.thymeleaf.spring4.templateresource.SpringResourceTemplateResource.reader(SpringResourceTemplateResource.java:103) ~[thymeleaf-spring4-3.0.3.RELEASE.jar!/:3.0.3.RELEASE]
...
```

This is my Configuration class:

```
@Bean
public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
    ThymeleafViewResolver resolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
    resolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
    resolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

    return resolver;
}

private TemplateEngine templateEngine() {
    SpringTemplateEngine engine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
    engine.addDialect(new Java8TimeDialect());
    engine.addTemplateResolver(templateResolver());
    engine.getConfiguration();

    return engine;
}

@Bean
public SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
    SpringResourceTemplateResolver templateResolver = new SpringResourceTemplateResolver();
    templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
    templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
    templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");
    return templateResolver;
}

@Bean
public UrlTemplateResolver urlTemplateResolver() {
    return new UrlTemplateResolver();
}
```

And the generated folder structure goes like this:
[image: Gradle build folder structure]

I've tried changing the prefix of the TemplateResolver to:

- /templates
- templates
- templates/
- /templates/
- classpath:templates/
- classpath:/templates/

My app is packed in a WAR file, with the following Gradle configuration:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse-wtp'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'war'

version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

configurations {
    providedRuntime
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.flywaydb:flyway-core')
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile ("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:3.0.0.RELEASE")
    compile ("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-java8time:3.0.0.RELEASE")
    compile ("io.github.jpenren:thymeleaf-spring-data-dialect:3.1.1")
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    runtime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools')
    runtime('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    providedRuntime('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
}

ext["thymeleaf.version"] = "3.0.3.RELEASE"
```

And this is the tree output for the unpacked WAR file, the folder 'templates' seems to be in the classpath:

```
.
|-- META-INF
|-- WEB-INF
|   |-- classes
|   |   |-- ar
|   |   |   `-- com
|   |   |       `-- reweb
|   |   |           `-- data
|   |   |               `-- repository
|   |   |-- db
|   |   |   `-- migration
|   |   |-- static
|   |   |   |-- bootstrap
|   |   |   |   |-- css
|   |   |   |   |-- fonts
|   |   |   |   `-- js
|   |   |   |-- css
|   |   |   |-- img
|   |   |   |-- jquery
|   |   |   |   `-- ui
|   |   |   |       |-- css
|   |   |   |       `-- js
|   |   |   `-- js
|   |   |       `-- articulos
|   |   `-- templates
|   |       |-- articulos
|   |       |   |-- aplicaciones
```

With no luck, any idea? Thanks

Comment: You haven't posted the error, or am I missing something?

Comment: sorry I forgot, added! @g00glen00b

Comment: Could you show a controller for the index page? You have double slashes in error message `templates//articulos/index.html`, it is strange.

Comment: my controller returns "articulos/index" as String

Comment: I would try also `classpath:templates` and/or `classpath:/templates`. Otherwise, can you make a mini project showing the problem ?

Comment: First of all, it really looks like it's not in your class path. build folder you listed is just that - build folder where grail will keep intermediate files it creates during a build. The big question is how it packs it. And unfortunately, there  are way to many ways to pack spring boot application with gradle. So, I'd suggest posting your gradle file here. Are you using war or jar? Unpack it and check that your files are there where you expect them to be. Also run it locally, but using your jar/war and java or tomcat (not gradle), you should see same error(s) as you would in beanstalk.

Comment: Thanks @Seva, I added my Gradle configuration and the folder structure of the unpacked WAR file, the 'templates' folder seems to be in the classpath..

Answer (score 0):

One thing to note is that if Thymeleaf doesn't find the template, a differently worded exception is thrown:

> org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving
>   template "articulos/index", template might not exist or might not be
>   accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers

FWIW, your code works fine on my machine with a minor modification (casting the TemplateEngine to a SpringTemplateEngine)

This makes me think that your problem is within the template itself - perhaps you are dynamically including a fragment (f.i. via `th:replace` ot `th:include`) that tries to link back to '/articulos/index.html' and that doesn't resolve correctly.

I'd try replacing the index.html with the most simple version possible, like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<div>
    Hello world!
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and see if it gets loaded.

If that works, try to double check the template's syntax, especially for the double slash (//), because that does look suspicious.

Comment: please note that the exception that is thrown is java.io.FileNotFoundException and the message states that the file doesn't exists, i'll try using SprintTemplateEngine